# Sending stucture containing mutable string to C from Python thru ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a structure which contains character array on C side

```
stuct s
{
    int x;
    char buffer[100];
}
```

and on my python side I define

```
class myS(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", c_int),
         ("buffer",type(create_string_buffer(100)))]
```

Now, when I do

```
buf = create_string_buffer(64)
s1 = myS(10,buf)
```

It gives me error

```
TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, c_char_Array_100 found
```

I want a string which will be changed by my C function. how to do it?

Comment: i have also tried c_char*100 in place of type(create_string_buffer(100)) resulting in same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create a buffer.  The buffer is in the structure when you instantiate it.

Here's a quick DLL:

```
#include <string.h>

struct s
{
    int x;
    char buffer[100];
};

__declspec(dllexport) void func(struct s* a)
{
    a->x = 5;
    strcpy(a->buffer,"here is the contents of the string.");
}
```

And here's Python code to call it:

```
import ctypes

class myS(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("x", ctypes.c_int),
        ("buffer",ctypes.c_char * 100)]

s1 = myS()
dll = ctypes.CDLL('test')
dll.func(ctypes.byref(s1))
print s1.buffer
print s1.x
```

Output:

```
here is the contents of the string.
5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a regular Python string to a 100*c_char field:

```
class myS(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", c_int),
         ("buffer", 100*c_char)]

s1 = myS(10, "foo")
s1.buffer = "bar"
```

If, however, you have a string buffer object, you can take its value:

```
buf = create_string_buffer(64) 
s1 = myS(10,buf.value)
```

Note also that

```
>>> type(create_string_buffer(100)) == 100*c_char
True
```

Comment: thanks janne.. Its working when I put the actual string inside myS in s1 defn but why does it create problem when I put variable in its place. Both should have worked in the same way..

Comment: @Sudip Use buf.value to get the string.